# How to fix price error for a product in Magento?

Tags: indexing, magento

I am trying to fix this product listing: http://shop.crystalvine.com/salt/blueberrysalt-c.html

You see in the dropdown there is an option for "refill" which is supposed to say $10.95 but says $45.95

When I log into Magento and click on Catalog --> Manage Products

There are f different listings for this product, differentiated by size/price. I try to edit the price by clicking "edit" on the product and under the price option on the left I edit the price and save.

But doing that to the products does not change the price on the live site when I edit the price for them.

Am I doing something wrong there? How do I change the price?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a configurable product.

Make sure you change the price for the simple product having that option or in the configurable product page, choose "Associated products" and make the price change there.
Then you probably must reindex your catalog (System -> Index managment).

Comment: do I need to re-index my catalog every time I change the prices?

Comment: also, where is the "Associated Products?" I am not seeing that. How do I get to it? Thanks!

Comment: get the configurable product sku, then in your catalog, edit that product. You will see on the left tabs the last is "Associated products".. I work on Mage in French, but this should be the right English term

Comment: You don't need to reindex your catalog manually every time you update a product, so long as you have "Update on Save" set on the index mode. However, I'm certain this is the default.